# window.location = link.href; not working

Tags: window.location

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$("#btn_AddToBasket").click( function(e) { 
e.preventDefault();
$('#main_container').css("display","block"); 
$('#alert_box').css("display","block");
});

$("#mbback").click( function() { 
$('#main_container').css("display","none"); 
$('#alert_box').css("display","none");
});

});
$("#mbgo").click( function() { 
window.location = link.href;
});
</script>
<div id="main_container" style="display:none;">
  <div id="alert_box" style="display:none;">
    <div class="alert_box_inner">
      <div id="message_container"><img src="-/resources/E5/160997/Image/logo.png" />
        <div id="message_title">You must be 18+</div>
        <div id="message_text">Please be aware that in order to purchase this product you must confirm that you are 18 years old or older. By clicking yes, you legally acknowledge that you are 18 years old or older</div>
        <div id="message_bottons"><a id="mbback" href="#">Go back</a><a id="mbgo" href="#">Yes, I&#39;m over 18</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm making age verification on page. When click #mbgo, page must open a page. But it is not opening. It must open #btn_AddToBasket's link

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in function

```
$("#mbgo").click( function() { 
    window.location = link.href;
});
```

The variable `link` in undefined, so your code should be
    `window.location = $("#btn_AddToBasket").attr("href");`